Converting R syntax to YAML syntax
How would I specify this code block
```{r, engine = "tikz", engine.opts=list(dvisvgm.opts = "--font-format=woff")}

```

using YAML syntax instead of R syntax? Something along the lines of:
```{r}
#| engine: tikz
#| engine.opts: ???
```


Try
#| engine: tikz
#| engine.opts: 
#|   dvisvgm.opts: "--font-format=woff"


Thanks! Removing -  from the last line yielded the correct output, so if you'd update your answer, then I'll accept it.

See my edit, is it now correct?
